# How to Stop or Close pytest Testing in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I am currently learning about code testing, and I have encountered an issue. When I use testing in VSCode and it starts running the tests, I am unable to stop or modify the tests.

I tried deleting the pytest cashes in the folder, and nothing happens. I searched for cancel or rollback button but i didn't find it!
I want to close the testing and test for something on another folder!!

Comment: tests are supposed to run fast, how long do your tests take to run, run the test in the terminal, you can then use `Ctrl+C`, read the doc of pytest

Comment: Check for test configuration files: In some cases, the test runner might be configured to automatically run tests upon saving a file or when specific events occur. Check if there are any configuration files in your project that trigger test runs automatically and modify them accordingly to prevent unwanted test runs

Comment: Thanks @rioV8 . I know about the terminal, but I want to do this through tests. my problem is not that the test is always running, I want to be able to close it whenever I want and test a new file whenever I want!

Comment: Thank you @MuratIshen. I checked my files, but there was no such thing.

Comment: my tests ONLY run when I press the run button in the TEST bar, and it has multiple run buttons, for individual tests, groups and files of tests, they run at most a few seconds so why try to stop it.

Comment: what do you mean with: **I want to do this through tests**

Comment: maybe you can start the test with a task and then call the command to kill all tasks if you want to stop

Comment: did you try pressing 'stop' button? another try is , configure VSCode settings: Open the VSCode settings (File > Preferences > Settings), search for "test" related settings, and see if there are any options that control the behavior of the test runner.